# What is the exact difference between the meanings of “constitute” and “conduce towards” in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the difference between the meanings of “constitute” and “conduce towards” in the following context? Based on the meaning of both, it seems to me that both mean something to the effect of “to amount to” or “contribute to the generation of”, but the “both” used by the writer seems to imply that they indicate two essentially different meanings.

> This book considers films as philosophical investigations. And submits
> that these investigations both **constitute** and **conduce towards**
> (both) true intel- lectual freedom and ecological wisdom. And that
> these two are in the end two sides of the same coin.

Comment: As you suggest, *constitute* may mean *to amount to* (or *comprise*), and *conduce* to may mean *contribute to the generation of* (or *lead to*). But these are different pairs of matched concepts and it is not clear why you think them the same.

Comment: Both is normally used to link two different things, which may be related but are not identical, e.g. "she is both beautiful and wise" or "he left both his hat and coat" or "I met both of them".